# SQL*Plus script pull issue

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus, terminal-services

Not sure you good folks can help with this.  I have a fellow on my team that is trying to run a SQL script from his home computer that connects to a terminal server. He has all his scripts in an easy to get to network folder that he can access.  However when he try's to run the script via File -> Open -> folder -> script.sql, the script will not execute.  The script does get pulled from the network folder and is inserted in the SQL*PLus window however it is inserted just below the prompt and the script does not execute.  My team and I all use a wide variety of terminal servers to work remotely (being that we're spread all over the country), and I have tried and duplicate his issue.  I log into the same terminal server, run the same version of SQL*plus and try to pull the same script (however my script is located in one of my network drive folders, not his) and every thing executes correctly.  I cannot make heads or tails of the issue.  Your help is much appreciated being that we have terabytes of data to pull and no time to do it in.

Comment: SQLPlus can easily read files from netrwork servers.  As for me, the following command works just fine:  `sqlplus schema/password@//192.168.0.11:1521/xe @"\\192.168.0.11\Users\Public\script.sql"`

Comment: Yes sir!  I can easily read files from all terminal servers, as can others on the team.  However, the one individual cannot seam to run the same scripts on the same servers.  no beuno.

Comment: Oh yeah! No es bueno.